# How do I join / merge / union two compressed MySQL MyISAM tables?

Tags: mysql, join, merge, compression, union

I have a large compressed MyISAM table that I am adding data to every month or so. Up until now the size of the tables have been manageable, but it's pretty tiresome to uncompress-insert-compress each and every time I want to add data.

So how can I do this without having to go through a uncompress-insert-compress cycle?

Also, I am a bit unsure of the nomenclature here. Is it a join, merge, or union? The [myisampack](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/myisampack.html) documentation mentions the `--join` option, but I have also found Ruben's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2780537/speed-up-of-readonly-myisam-table) talking about a `union`.

What is best practice here? Now I start and end with table_{archive,new_data}.{frm,MYD,MYI} and nothing else. Would different ways of doing it also involve renaming the table files (as mentioned in the myisampack docs)?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to insert any record into a compressed table. You have to create a new one for new data , I think you have one on hand.
So you can join two tables one compressed the other not in to a new compressed table. Then issue myisampack -rg command to rebuild keys.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/myisampack.html